# Is there an equivalent to `Array::sample` for hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash, random

I'm looking to extract n random key-value pairs from a hash.

Comment: It would help if you'd show a sample of the input hash and explain a bit more what you are attempting to use it for.  Grabbing random key/value pairs from a hash is rarely useful, except maybe for testing with random inputs to something, from a known set. It's a very odd request in my experience and makes me think something's wonky.

Comment: i have this same need.  i have a hash of hashes, it could also have been stored as an array of hashes.  and it makes sense to be able to grab n random entries from an array.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
Hash[original_hash.to_a.sample(n)]
```

For Ruby 2.1,

```
original_hash.to_a.sample(n).to_h
```

Comment: is this slow, or a bad idea, if i am grabbing data from a bigger size hash? would there be an alternate approach to attempt then?

Comment: @appleLover I can't think of anything better.

Comment: I was curious so I benchmarked it... in case anyone else is curious https://gist.github.com/bendyorke/924612cba7432cbf36dd

Answer (score 43):

I don't know of such method. Still you can do something like:

```
h[h.keys.sample]
```

If you need to sample more than one element the code will have to be a bit more complicated.

EDIT: to get key value pairs instead of only the value you can do something like:

```
keys_sample = h.keys.sample(n)
keys_sample.zip(keys_sample.map{|k| h[k])
```

Comment: This doesn't return a key-value pair as the OP wanted, only the value for a random key.

Comment: @theTinMan true. Point taken. Truth is sawa's solution is the neatest solution for **that** problem

Answer (score 6):

Reading the top ranked answers, I'd go with *it depends*:

1. If you want to sample *only one* element from the hash, [@Ivaylo Strandjev's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454655/341929) only relies on hash lookup and `Array#sample`:

   ```
   hsh[hsh.keys.sample]
   ```
2. To sample *multiple* hash elements, [@sawa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454790/341929) leverages `Array#to_h`:

   ```
   hsh.to_a.sample(n).to_h
   ```

---

Note that, [as @cadlac mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454632/is-there-an-equivalent-to-arraysample-for-hashes-in-ruby#comment36519263_15454790), `hsh.to_a.sample.to_h` won't work as expected. It will raise

```
TypeError: wrong element type String at 0 (expected array)
```

because `Array#sample` in this case returns just the element array, and not the array containing the element array.

A workaround is his solution, providing an `n = 1` as an argument:

```
hsh.to_a.sample(1).to_h
```

---

*PS: not looking for upvotes, only adding it as an explanation for people newer to Ruby.*

Comment: Depending on your format, `hsh[hsh.keys.sample].keys` might also be the solution, if you are looking for sub keys under a particular hash key. For example a `users['John Doe'] = user_hash` not sure if there is a more 'ruby' way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If your sample has only one element, you could use this:

```
sample = h.keys.sample
h.select { |k,v| k == sample }
```

Or if your sample contains more than one element, use this:

```
n = 2
sample = h.keys.sample(n)
h.select { |k,v| sample.include?(k) }
```

Comment: If the h has only one element, then use `= h`. Anything else is overkill.

Comment: I said if the **sample** only has one element. My example assumes a hash with more than one key-value pair. There would be no point in sampling a hash with one element...

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this:

```
rank_hash = {"Listen" => 1, "Download" => 60, "Share" => 150, "Purchase" => 700 }

rank_array = rank_hash.to_a
```

Than call this to get random array sample of the k/v pair:

```
rank_array[rand(0..3)]
```

or this to not hard-code the arrays length:

```
rank_array[rand(0..(rank_array.length) -1)]
```

Example:

```
["Download", 60]
```