# avoid keys duplication to get a random hash key

Tags: ruby

I need to pick a hash entry at random, so I do

```
h = {1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}
k = h.keys.sample
result = h[k]
```

Since `h.keys` creates a new array I do not like it. Is there a way to avoid creating a new array every time?

Comment: Why do you not like that it creates a new array? Unless this code is in a hotspot the overhead here shouldn't be terribly significant.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454632/is-there-an-equivalent-to-arraysample-for-hashes-in-ruby for a similar discussion

Comment: I agree with the comments saying that I should not spend time on this, so I ended up with the same code as I have posted. I just asked out of curiosity. I think it can be done elegantly by enumerating the keys and picking each key with decreasing probability.

Comment: @akonsu: Calling h.keys still creates a new array.

Comment: @Linuxios: yes, that is the main concern of the post. what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not generate another array. On average **hash_random_value** will iterate halfway through the given hash to produce a random value.

```
def hash_random_value(h)
  i = rand(h.length)
  h.each_with_index do |(_, v), i2|
    return v if i == i2
  end
end

h = {1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}
hash_random_value(h)
```

This being said, you should optimize only when you are certain you need to do that. The only way you can know is to profile your code, otherwise you are most likely doing premature optimisation. I.e. complicating your code and increasing the chance of introducing bugs--sometimes even decreasing the performance of your program. Your original solution is much easier to understand than mine, and it is immediately obvious that it is correct.

Comment: yes. cool. this is very close to my solution, that I added as an answer too, but is more efficient. thanks.

Comment: You're creating an Enumerator object :)

Comment: is enumerator as expensive as a duplicate array?

Comment: In practice neither is really expensive. In theory an enumerator requires a constant amount of memory, while an array's memory consumption grows with the size of the array. On the other hand, it is less cpu intensive to iterate over an array than an enumerator. You can often trade memory consumption for cpu cycles and vice versa. Either way, if this really matters, you should profile your code: https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to first reiterate what most people are saying: this probably doesn't matter.

Second, I'll point out that it sure seems like you want a random *value*, not a random *key*.  Maybe that's just because your example snippet of code doesn't show what you're really doing.

If you very frequently need a random value, and very infrequently update the Hash, I'd recommend caching the values any time the Hash is modified and then taking a random value from the cache.  One way to do that might be like this:

```
class RandomValueHash < Hash
  def []=(k, v)
    super(k, v)
    @values = self.values
  end

  def sample_value
    @values ||= self.values
    @values.sample
  end
end

rvh = RandomValueHash[{1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}]
rvh.sample_value
# => "one"
rvh[4] = 'four'
rvh[5] = 'five'
rvh.sample_value
# => "four"
```

Of course, if you really do want a random key rather than value, the exact same concept applies.  Either way, this avoids recreating the Array every time you get a value; it only creates it when necessary.

Comment: This captures what I was suggesting, but in an automated rather than manual fashion.  Kudos!  By my benchmarking this is substantially faster than the accepted solution, and the relative performance gets even better as the number of values in the hash increases.

Comment: @pjs Thanks!  I'd be thoroughly confused if it weren't substantially faster than the accepted solution, which has to walk through the Hash to reach the desired key/value every time.  In you benchmarks, did you compare the accepted solution to the original question?  I'd be curious how much it actually helps in practice.

Comment: I'll add my benchmark code to my response, so people can come to their own conclusions.

Comment: thanks, I was concerned not about speed but about memory consumption. here is an article that I find interesting: https://github.com/blog/1489-hey-judy-don-t-make-it-bad

Comment: @akonsu If your focus is memory consumption, then you should be liking solutions that generate the key set once and keep reusing it.  Darshan's solution is pretty elegant: it's efficient on memory, fast on the benchmarks, and doesn't require manual upkeep.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
h = {1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}
k = h.keys
...
result = h[k.sample]
```

You can do the `result = h[k.sample]` times as often as you like, and it won't be regenerating the `k` array.  However, you should regenerate `k` any time `h` changes.

**ADDENDUM**: I'm throwing in benchmark code for several of the proposed solutions.  Enjoy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'benchmark'

NUM_ITERATIONS = 1_000_000

def hash_random_value(h)
  i = rand(h.length)
  h.each_with_index do |(_, v), i2|
    return v if i == i2
  end
end

class RandomValueHash < Hash
  def []=(k, v)
    super(k, v)
    @values = self.values
  end

  def sample_value
    @values ||= self.values
    @values.sample
  end
end

Benchmark.bmbm do |b|
  h = {1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}

  b.report("original proposal") do
    NUM_ITERATIONS.times {k = h.keys.sample; result = h[k]}
  end

  b.report("hash_random_value") do
    NUM_ITERATIONS.times {result = hash_random_value(h)}
  end

  b.report("manual keyset") do
    k = h.keys
    NUM_ITERATIONS.times {result = h[k.sample]}
  end

  rvh = RandomValueHash[{1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}]

  b.report("RandomValueHash") do
    NUM_ITERATIONS.times {result = rvh.sample_value}
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the same as the OP's solution.

Comment: It does at least attempt to adress OP's concerns regarding efficiency, and could well end up being the easiest compromise.

Comment: @NeilSlater, true, I'm trying a C solution.

Comment: @Linuxios Not really - my intention was that the code above the `...` is done once, and generates a single array of keys which can be accessed hundreds of times below the `...` without a need to regenerate the array unless `h` changes.

Comment: Good work on the benchmarks! To find the best solution, benchmarks should measure code performing all sub-tasks in realistic amounts, and with realistic amounts of data. It is highly unlikely that the OP wants to create a 3-element hash once, then sample it a million times. But no figures have been stated, so is up to OP to extend this if required to figure out the best solution for his problem.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks.  But I disagree about performing all sub-tasks in realistic amounts to benchmark. Large amounts of repetition give more stable estimates of the **relative costs**, and can be scaled by the repetition amount to indicate the unit sub-task cost.  What I saw in the benchmark is that in practice, this is a non-issue as many have pointed out. But I also saw that the accepted solution is the slowest, about 3 times slower than the original approach that motivated the OP's question, and when there are more elements in the hash its relative performance is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make the random sample a lot, and need it to be efficient, then perhaps a Ruby `Hash` is not the right data structure or storage for your problem. Even a wrapper class that maintained `Hash` and `Array` attributes together might work well - if for instance for every write to the hash you needed to read 20 random samples.

Whether or not that works for you not only depends on the ratio of reading and writing, it also relates to the logical structure of your problem data (as opposed to how you've chosen to represent it in your solution).

But before you set off on re-thinking your problem, you need to have a practical need for higher performance in the affected code. The hash would need to be pretty large in order to have a noticeable cost to fetching its keys. `h.keys` takes about 250ms when the hash has 1 million entries on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Hashes don't have an index so you either convert them to an Array and pick a random index or you Enumerate your hash for a random number of times. You should benchmark which method is fastest but I doubt you can avoid creating a new object.

If you don't care about your object you could shift it's keys for a random number of times but then you'd cerate Arrays for return values.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a gigantic hash, this is a pointless concern. Ruby is no efficiency powerhouse, and if you're that worried about this, you should be using C(++).

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
h.each_with_index.reduce(nil) {|m, ((_, v), i)|
  rand(i + 1) == 0 ? v : m
}
```