# To obtain random pair from Hash

Tags: ruby

Part of `class KeyServer`

```
@generated_keys = Hash.new

def generate_key
    key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    while(purged_keys.include?(key))
      key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
    #add new key to hashes that maintain records
    @generated_keys.merge!({key => Time.now})
    @all_keys.merge!(@generated_keys) { |key, v1, v2| v1 }
    return key
  end
```

And I use the generated keys here: (I need a random pair to be selected and allotted to user)

```
def get_available_key
    if(generated_keys.empty?)
      return "404. No keys available"
    else
      new_key = @generated_keys.to_a.sample(1)
      @generated_keys.delete(new_key[0][0].to_s)
      @blocked_keys.merge!({new_key[0][0].to_s => Time.now})
    end
  end
```

This is how I use it in `Sinatra`

```
api = KeyServer.new
get '/block_key' do 
  api.get_available_key
end
```

I tried the solution mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454632/is-there-an-equivalent-to-arraysample-for-hashes-in-ruby) but when I run this as part of my `Sinatra` server I obtain an `Internal Server Error: No implicit conversion from Array to String`

How do I make this work? Any other method to obtain a random pair from a `Hash` would be welcome.

Comment: On what line are you getting there error?

Comment: @JeffPrice I obtain the error when I try to access `localhost:4567/block_key` (4567 is the default port where Sinatra runs) and after I have generated some keys

Comment: @YuHao I have added more of the code. The remaining is, I am sure, irrelevant to my problem

Comment: instead of `to_a.sample(1)` why not `keys.sample(1)` since you only care about the key anyway? Also `get_available_key` will return a `Hash` that is `@blocked_keys` or a `String` in the event `generated_keys` is empty. Is that the intended result because the method name suggests it should return a single key? Also returning 2 different object types from the same method will make handling a little more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a random element from a `Hash` to return as a `Hash` you could simply patch `Hash` to do this like

```
class Hash
  def sample(n)
    Hash[to_a.sample(n)]
  end
end
```

Then call like

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} 
h.sample(1)
#=> {b: 2}
h.sample(2) 
#=> {:b=>2, :a=>1}
```

**Note:** I used `Hash::[]` for compatibility purposes in Ruby 2.X you could use `to_h` instead.

Other than that I think there might be a few more issues with your code and it's return values.

If I were to refactor your code the sample code above would not be needed I would instead go with something like it would be something like

```
def get_available_key
  if(generated_keys.empty?)
    {"error" => "404. No keys available"}
  else
    new_key = @generated_keys.keys.sample(1)
    @generated_keys.delete(new_key)
    @blocked_keys.merge!({new_key => Time.now})[new_key]
  end
end
```

This way it will always respond with a `Hash` object for handling purposes and it need not worry about multidimensional arrays at all.

I would also change the initial code to be more like this

```
def create_new_key 
  key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  purged_keys.include?(key) ? create_new_key  : key
end
def generate_key
  key = create_new_key 
  #add new key to hashes that maintain records
  @generated_keys.merge!({key => Time.now})
  @all_keys.merge!(@generated_keys) { |key, v1, v2| v1 }
  key
end
def add_to_key_chain(length)
  @generated_keys ||= {}
  length.times do 
    create_new_key
  end
end
```

Although I don't know what the `purged_keys` method looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`hash.to_a.sample` evaluates to a two-element array where the first element is some key and the second is the corresponding value.

When you call delete you should be using `hash.delete(new_key[0])` instead of `hash.delete(new_key[0][0].to_s)`.

Comment: `hash.to_a.sample(1)` returns a 2 dimensional array and not an element. So if I access `new_key[0]`, I will be accessing another array

Comment: `new_key[0].class` returns `Array` while `new_key[0][0].class` returns `String`