# Access random pair from a 'large' hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to access a random pair of key-value from a very large hash.
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454632/is-there-an-equivalent-to-arraysample-for-hashes) answer, which led me to this solution -

```
original_hash.to_a.sample(n).to_h
```

It works well, but it converts whole hash to `array` for each call, 

Is there any other way this can be done efficiently for a very large `hash`?

Comment: Write the issue fully in the main text. Don't let the reader follow a link to understand it. Don't omit the explanation in the main text just because you think you wrote it int the title.

Comment: @sawa this IS exactly the excerpt I used from the link, the line of code which is converting the hash to array and back to hash.
And this is what I am looking an alternative for.

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: @sawa updated my answer to accommodate your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: A small memory improvement is `original_hash.keys.sample` since you can then retrieve the values from the random keys and thus avoid converting the entire hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a random number first then go with something like

```
n = rand(large_hash.count)
new_h = [large_hash.find.with_index { |_h,i| i == n }].to_h
#alternatively new_h = large_hash.find.with_index { |h,i| [h].to_h if i == n }
```

Now `new_h` will be a random key value pair `Hash` from the `large_hash` without the converting the whole `large_hash` to an `Array`. Or a more obtuse version:

```
large_hash.find.with_index.with_object({}) do |((k,v),i),obj|
  obj[k] = v if i == n
end
```

Note: this will select **a single** pair

Comment: Time complexity here is `O(N)`, which is comparable (same?) to code in the question. But at least memory complexity is way better, yes.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `sample` isn't defined on `Enumerable` to begin with. The implementation would look just like this.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be if you save all the keys in a caching variable and then randomly access one key and return the key value. e.g.

```
def random_paire(amount: 1)
  @keys ||= @large_hash.keys
  @keys.sample(amount).map {|key| { key => @large_hash[key] } }
end
```

But I think this is only practical if you will use this in a class. It is not such an good option to use it for a globaly availalble method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone` to create a shallow copy of the original hash, `rand` to generate a random number based on the hash length, and then `shift` to grab the `key:value` pair at the randomly generated "index".  In practice it might look like this:

```
new_hash = original_hash.clone
rand(original_hash.size).times do
 new_hash.shift
end

new_hash.shift
```

Ran a few quick benchmarks and it seems to shave about 40% off of the execution time as compared to the `original_hash.to_a.sample(n).to_h` approach mentioned in the OP.

It should be noted that the `rand(Integer)` method randomly selects an integer value that is more than or equal to zero and LESS THAN the chosen integer value.  That means the last `new_hash.shift` is absolutely necessary to be sure the operation pulls the first `key:value` pair from `original_hash` if the number randomly chosen is zero.  If the highest possible number(hash length-1) is chosen, then the final `new_hash.shift` will allow the last `key:value` pair to be selected.  It's like a pseudo hash index where 0 is the first item and length-1 is the last item.